# Using Inno Setup to tell Windows my app can open a public file type

Tags: windows, inno-setup

There are a number of answers already having to do with creating new file associations. I don't want a new file association *per se*. My app can open **PDF** files. All I want to do is configure my installer such that, after installation, when a user right-clicks a PDF file, my app will show up in the "Open with..." list in the popup that appears. My app certainly should not be the default program for PDF. Is there a way to do this with Inno Setup?

Comment: Have a look at this webpage https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/ and see if you can follow thos einstructions manually. If you can then just replicate the registry key calls in Inno Setup.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That looks like it should work. I'm going to give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That does work as advertised, but it's a much broader scope than I'm looking for. It applies to all files, not just .pdf files. I guess what I'm really looking for is how to edit the Registry to add my app to the "Open with..." list for .pdf files. Actually, I did add it to that list, but it isn't enough. I seem to have missed a step.

Comment: Maybe ask on the power user site. Tackle it from that angle.

Comment: @vacuumhead How to register for a specific file type is shown in my answer to the duplicate question.